# WildFly integration with ActiveMQ using JCA resource adapter

Tags: jms, wildfly, activemq-classic, integration

I am trying to integrate ActiveMQ 5.15.13 with WildFly 21.0.1.Final using the ActiveMQ JCA resource adapter. However, I am getting errors while doing it. I was able to integrate WildFly 9 with ActiveMQ 5.10.
I'm getting the following errors:

```
2021-01-22 19:20:18,577 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ra.deployer."activemq-rar-5.15.13.rar": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ra.deployer."activemq-rar-5.15.13.rar": WFLYJCA0046: Failed to start RA deployment [activemq-rar-5.15.13.rar]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService$1.run(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:176)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: IJ020056: Deployment failed: file:/opt/apps/MerckContivoPilot/wildfly-21.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/activemq-rar-5.15.13.rar/
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:2058)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService$WildFLyRaDeployer.doDeploy(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:233)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:126)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.validator.ValidatorException: Severity: WARNING
Section: 20.7
Description: Invalid config-property-type for AdminObject.
Code: Class: org.apache.activemq.pool.XaPooledConnectionFactory Property: tmFromJndi Type: boolean

Severity: ERROR
Section: 13.4.2.2
Description: An ActivationSpec class must implement the ActivationSpec interface
Code: org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQActivationSpec

Severity: ERROR
Section: 5.3.1
Description: A ResourceAdapter must implement the javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapter interface.
Code: org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQResourceAdapter

Severity: ERROR
Section: 6.5.3.2
Description: The class must implement the javax.resource.spi.ManagedConnectionFactory interface.
Code: org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory
```

Resource Adapter configuration

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0">
    <resource-adapters>
        <resource-adapter id="activemq-ra">
            <archive>activemq-rar-5.15.13.rar</archive>
            <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
            <config-property name="ServerUrl">tcp://localhost:61616?soTimeout=20000&amp;connectionTimeout=10000</config-property>
            <config-property name="UserName">defaultUser</config-property>
            <config-property name="UseInboundSession">false</config-property>
            <config-property name="Password">defaultPassword</config-property>
            <connection-definitions>
                <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory" use-ccm="true">
                    <xa-pool>
                        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
                    </xa-pool>
                    <timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    </timeout>
                </connection-definition>
            </connection-definitions>
            <admin-objects>
                <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/queue/XMLPublishQueue" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="XMLPublishQueue">
                    <config-property name="PhysicalName">XMLPublishQueue</config-property>
                </admin-object>
                <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/queue/SupportTasksQueue" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="SupportTasksQueue">
                    <config-property name="PhysicalName">SupportTasksQueue</config-property>
                </admin-object>
            </admin-objects>
        </resource-adapter>
    </resource-adapters>
</subsystem>
```

Downloaded rar from
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-rar/5.15.13

Tried both ways (updating rar and without updating it) by following the below guides

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1124023

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/integrate-activemq-with-wildfly

Update: Issue started when I added third-party jars through global-modules section under ee subsystem. I was adding java ee api jar

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @JustinBertram updated my post with Resource Adapter configuration. Tried by deploying original rar directly and also tried by updating ServerUrl in ra.xml and deployed repackaged rar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deployed the ActiveMQ 5.13.13 JCA resource adapter to Wildfly 21.0.1.Final and I didn't see the same logging you saw. Everything appears to be working just fine. Here's what I did:

1. Download & unzip [WildFly 21.0.1.Final](https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/21.0.1.Final/wildfly-21.0.1.Final.zip).
2. Download the [ActiveMQ 5.15.13 JCA RA](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-rar/5.15.13) and copy it to `standalone/deployments`.
3. Added this to `standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml`:

   ```xml
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0">
       <resource-adapters>
           <resource-adapter id="activemq-ra-5">
               <archive>activemq-rar-5.15.13.rar</archive>
               <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
               <config-property name="ServerUrl">tcp://localhost:61616?soTimeout=20000&amp;connectionTimeout=10000</config-property>
               <config-property name="UserName">defaultUser</config-property>
               <config-property name="UseInboundSession">false</config-property>
               <config-property name="Password">defaultPassword</config-property>
               <connection-definitions>
                   <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory" use-ccm="true">
                       <xa-pool>
                           <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                           <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
                       </xa-pool>
                       <timeout>
                           <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                           <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                       </timeout>
                   </connection-definition>
               </connection-definitions>
               <admin-objects>
                   <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/queue/XMLPublishQueue" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="XMLPublishQueue">
                       <config-property name="PhysicalName">XMLPublishQueue</config-property>
                   </admin-object>
                   <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/queue/SupportTasksQueue" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="SupportTasksQueue">
                       <config-property name="PhysicalName">SupportTasksQueue</config-property>
                   </admin-object>
               </admin-objects>
           </resource-adapter>
       </resource-adapters>
   </subsystem>
   ```
4. Updated the `jms-connection-factory` attribute in the `default-bindings` element of the `ee` subsystem to use `java:/ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory`:

   ```xml
   <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" jms-connection-factory="java:/ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
   ```
5. Updated the `resource-adapter-name` attribute of the `mdb`/`resource-adapter-ref` element of the `ejb3` subsystem to be `${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-rar-5}`:

   ```xml
   <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-rar-5}"/>
   ```
6. Started WildFly using `./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml`

Given that all this works normally I would say your problem is your global module, especially since it includes Java EE API classes. Application jars and library jars should *not* include Java/Jakarta EE API classes. The EE server (e.g. WildFly) provides all those. If you (or someone else) provides their own then that will cause classloading problems and that, in turn, will cause a lot of other weird problems. To reiterate, there's absolutely no reason for you to package Java/Jakarta EE API classes with your application or libraries deployed on the server.

Comment: Strange. Have you downloaded the Resource Adapter from same location? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-rar/5.15.13

Comment: I am also able to deploy without any changes. But don't we need to update default jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" under ee subsystem to 'java:/ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory'. When i update this, i am getting all the above errors

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comments. Hope that helps!

Comment: Are you changing any other configuration? Are you deploying anything else (e.g. an MDB)?

Comment: Started from original standalone-full-ha.xml and was able to deploy successfully till i add global-modules section under ee subsystem. Updated mdb(ejb3 subsystem), default jms factory(ee subsystem), added datasources successfully. But when i add global-modules section, i got the error

Comment: What exactly are you adding related to global-modules? I don't see any reference to that in either of the tutorials you cited. Please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: It is not related to resource adapter. I am placing 3rd party jars in a directory (com/custom/jars/main) under modules and referring it under global-modules so that those jars will be available to all the deployments.

          <global-modules>
                <module name="com.custom.jars" slot="main"/>
          </global-modules>
was following this guide for global-modules https://docs.wildfly.org/21/Admin_Guide.html#EE

Comment: Do those 3rd party jars contain any Java EE API classes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227732/discussion-between-sumanth-and-justin-bertram).